# How to save the model comparison dataframe from compare_models() in pycaret?

Tags: pandas, pycaret

I want to save the model comparison data frame from compare_models() in pycaret.

```
# load dataset
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
diabetes = get_data('diabetes')

# init setup
from pycaret.classification import *
clf1 = setup(data = diabetes, target = 'Class variable')

# compare models
best = compare_models()
```

[image]

i.e. this data frame as shown above.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is :

```
df = pull()
```

by Goosang Yu from the pycaret slack community.

Comment: I would also add that `pull()` should be called just after `compare_models()` as `pull()` returns the latest displayed table as a dataframe. 

Additionally, if you have defined an experiment in a variable, like this `exp_1 = ClassificationExperiment()` do not forget to run `exp_1.pull()` instead. Most of the documentation usually do not save the Pycaret experiment in a variable so in the code examples they avoid it as Pycaret infers it from the environment. I prefer to use the Pycaret experiment in a variable and I share this advice if anyone else uses it too.

Answer (score -1):

`compare_models()` returns a pandas dataframe, containing the information of the list of models. Hence, you only need to save a dataframe, which can be for example achieved with `best.to_csv(path)`. If you want to save the object in a different format (pickle, xml, ...), you can refer to [pandas i/o documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html).

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Seems compare_models() returns the best model object but not a pandas df. Therefore this method will give: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-f7df6de90b9e> in <module>()
----> 1 best.to_csv("compare_models.csv")

AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'to_csv'